# Confused by behavior of ListLogPlot in Mathematica 10

Tags: plotting, ticks

I have a notebook I originally created in Mathematica 8, where the following (simplified) code worked fine.

```
ListLogPlot[Table[{1.2 z, z^2}, {z, 0., 3., .25}], PlotMarkers-> None, 
   FrameLabel -> {"z(nm)", "\[Tau](z)"}]
```

However, when I run this code in the upgraded version it produces a plot that shows no frameticks or tick labels!  If I save the plot, and upload it to the friendly people at StackOverflow to show my problem, everything looks fine, like so:

[image: ListLogPlot example]

However, in my actual notebook, it looks like this (from a screenshot)

[image]

Note, it makes no difference if I include `FrameTicks->Automatic` in my `ListLogPlot` command.

At the top of my notebook I set

```
SetOptions[ListLogPlot, Axes -> None, Joined -> True, Frame -> True, 
GridLines -> None, PlotStyle -> Table[{Thickness[.0075], ColorData[1, i]}, {i, 1, 20}], PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 20}, 
LabelStyle -> {Automatic, FontSize -> 22, Bold, Black}, PlotRange -> All]
```

which never created a problem in v8.  What the heck is going on here?  How can I get the frameticks to show in my notebook?

Answer (score 3):

```
$Version
```

> "10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (September 10, 2014)"

The default option values are

```
Options[ListLogPlot, {Axes, Frame, Joined}]
```

> {Axes -> True, Frame -> False, Joined -> False}

So there should be Axes rather than a Frame and no line

```
ListLogPlot[Table[{1.2 z, z^2},
  {z, 0., 3., .25}],
 PlotMarkers -> None,
 FrameLabel -> {"z(nm)", "\[Tau](z)"}]
```

[image]

Try this

```
ListLogPlot[Table[{1.2 z, z^2},
  {z, 0., 3., .25}],
 Joined -> True,
 PlotMarkers -> None,
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {"z(nm)", "\[Tau](z)"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bob.  I have done exactly what you did.  In the current notebook I am working in, it reproduces my problem.  If I copy the exact same code into a new, unsaved notebook,  everything shows up fine, as in your answer.  I'm not sure what the difference could even be.  I just need a hint where to look for the problem -- I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Another note I just discovered.  If I save the notebook, exit completely out of mathematica (not simply kill the kernal or Clear["Global`*'"]) then when I open the notebook again, all the tick marks are visible.  Very bizarre.